# How to Select columns based on the values of the GroupBy column without knowing any specific values in Spark

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have some data like this:

```
val simpleData = Seq(
 ("James",   "Sales",     3000,  1, -1, -1),
 ("Michael", "Sales",     4600,  2, -1, -1),
 ("Robert",  "Sales",     4100,  3, -1, -1),
 ("Maria",   "Finance",   3000, -1,  1, -1),
 ("James",   "Sales",     3000,  4, -1, -1),
 ("Scott",   "Finance",   3300, -1,  2, -1),
 ("Jen",     "Finance",   3900, -1,  3, -1),
 ("Jeff",    "Marketing", 3000, -1, -1,  1),
 ("Kumar",   "Marketing", 2000, -1, -1,  2),
 ("Saif",    "Sales",     4100,  5, -1, -1)
)
```

DataFrame is defined as the following

```
val df = simpleData.toDF("employee_name", "department", "salary", "sales_no", "finance_no", "marketing_no")
```

I would like to list all the employee numbers for each department like this:

```
+----------+------------------------+
|department|collect_list(finance_no)|
+----------+------------------------+
|Sales     |[1,2,3,4,5]             |
|Finance   |[1, 2, 3]               |
|Marketing |[1,2]                   |
+----------+------------------------+
```

I defined a UDF like to this attempting to return the employee number column based on the value of department,

```
val departmentToNo = (dept: String) => {
 dept match {
  case "Sales" => "sales_no"
  case "Finance" => "finance_no"
  case "Marketing" => "marketing_no"
 }
}
df.groupBy($"department")
  .agg(collect_list(udf(departmentToNo).apply($"department"))
  .as("newColumn"))
```

But what I got is the following,

```
+----------+-----------------------------------------------------------+
|department|newColumn.                                                 |
+----------+-----------------------------------------------------------+
|Sales     |[sales_no,sales_no,sales_no,sales_no,sales_no]             |
|Finance   |[finance_no, finance_no, finance_no        ]               |
|Marketing |[marketing_no, marketing_no]                               |
+----------+-----------------------------------------------------------+
```

How can I achieve this in Spark SQL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use scala curring features which will reduce the complexity try the following code snippet:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.col
var column_to_compare = df.select("sales_no","finance_no","marketing_no").columns.map(x => col(x))
df.withColumn("summary", column_to_compare.reduce((c1,c2) => when(c1 > 0,c1).otherwise(c2))).groupBy("department").agg(collect_list("summary") as "all_cols_unique").show
```

Answer (score 1):

What if you just use the `CASE` statement?

```
df.groupBy('department)
  .agg(collect_list(expr("CASE WHEN department = 'Sales' THEN sales_no WHEN department = 'Finance' THEN finance_no ELSE marketing_no END")).alias("new"))
  .show
```

The result is:

```
+----------+---------------+
|department|            new|
+----------+---------------+
|     Sales|[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]|
|   Finance|      [1, 2, 3]|
| Marketing|         [1, 2]|
+----------+---------------+
```

Comment: As soon as the columns will improve so each time we have to make changes into the case statement which will improve time complexity.